# Getting bad request with CURL in PHP posting XML data

Tags: php, libcurl

I am using PHP CURL to post some xml data to another server using that IP, i fullfilled all the requirements for making it work, but still getting an error of "BAD REQUEST".

Have a look on the code below.

```
 $var2 ="<doc><item>Some content.</item></doc>";
    $url = "server IP";     
    $header  = "POST HTTP/1.1 \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($var2)." \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
    $header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
    $header .= $var2;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

    // Get Response
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 


    if(curl_errno($ch))

        print curl_error($ch);
    else
        curl_close($ch);

    echo  $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using this as request-line :

```
$header  = "POST HTTP/1.1 \r\n";
```

According to the [**HTTP 1.1 RFC**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), the [`**Request-Line**`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) should look like this :

```
Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF
```

So, it seems you should add an URI between `POST` and `HTTP/1.1`

*(But, before coding that, read what I've written in the next paragraphs of my answer)*

Then, you are passing a lot of things as **`CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`**.

I don't think you can pass all those header using that option (quoting) :

> Valid values are things like "`GET`", "`POST`", "`CONNECT`" and so on;
>   
> i.e. Do not enter a whole HTTP request line here. 
> For
>   instance, entering "`GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`" would be
>   incorrect.

If you want to specify custom headers (it seems you do), you should use the **`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`** option, instead of `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` *(quoting the documentation of the first one)* :

> An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format
>   `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`